# Solve the partial differential equation $5U_x+cU=xy$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I have this problem:

$$ 5U_x+cU=xy $$

where $U:=U(x,y)$. Now I have been racking my brains, and I am really struggling with solving this. I tried an array of ways: looking at the ODE equivalent in an attempt to try and get some sort of characteristic polynomial and translate this back to a PDE setting but it just isn't working out. I was thinking as to whether it's possible to take an integrating factor approach, but again, struggling to see what it might be.

Any hints will be much appreciated for this one.

EDIT: Is the integrating factor $y$ as we are holding $x$ constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve the ODE
$$\frac{d}{dx}U(x,y)+\frac{c}{5}U(x,y)=\frac{xy}{5}$$
for all fixed $y$.

So you have the integrating factor
$$\exp\left(\int_{x_0}^x \frac{c}{5}dx\right)=A\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)$$

$$A\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)\frac{d}{dx}U(x,y)+A\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)\frac{c}{5}U(x,y)=A\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)\frac{xy}{5}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)U(x,y)\right]=\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)\frac{xy}{5}$$

$$\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)U(x,y)=\frac{y}{5}\int x\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)dx$$
$$=\frac{y}{c}\left[x\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)-\int\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)dx\right]$$
$$=\frac{y}{c}\left[x\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)-\frac{5}{c}\exp\left(\frac{c}{5}x\right)+B\right]$$

$$U(x,y)=\frac{y}{c}\left[x-\frac{5}{c}+B\exp\left(-\frac{c}{5}x\right)\right]$$
$$=\frac{xy}{c}-\frac{5}{c^2}y+Ky\exp\left(-\frac{c}{5}x\right)$$

Comment: I think it's easier to apply the formula for $\dot U +a(x)U=b(x)$:
$$
U=e^{-\int a(x)dx}(K+\int e^{\int a(x)dx}b(x)dx)
$$
where $a(x)=c/5, b(x)=yx/5$